# Averaging Panel Data in SAS

Tags: sas

I have panel data set that looks like this

```
ID    Usage     month    
1234    2        -2  
1234    4        -1
1234    3         1
1234    2         2
2345    5        -2
2345    6        -1
2345    3         1
2345    6         2
```

Obviously there are more ID variables and usage data, but this is the general form. I want to average the usage data when the month column is negative, and when it is positive for each ID. In other words for each unique ID, average the usage for negative months and for positive months. My goal is to get something like this.

```
ID   avg_usage_neg   avg_usage_pos
1234     3                  2.5
2345     5.5                4.5
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a few options for you.

First create the test data:

```
data sample;
  input ID    
        Usage     
        month;
datalines;
1234    2        -2  
1234    4        -1
1234    3         1
1234    2         2
2345    5        -2
2345    6        -1
2345    3         1
2345    6         2
;
run;
```

Here's an SQL solution:

```
proc sql noprint;
  create table result as
  select id,
         avg(ifn(month < 0, usage, .)) as avg_usage_neg,
         avg(ifn(month > 0, usage, .)) as avg_usage_pos
  from sample
  group by 1
  ;
quit;
```

Here's a datastep / proc means solution:

```
data sample2;
  set sample;
  usage_neg = ifn(month < 0, usage, .);
  usage_pos = ifn(month > 0, usage, .);
run;

proc means data=sample2 noprint missing nway;
  class id;
  var usage_neg usage_pos;
  output out=result2 mean=;
run;
```